# AWS Cloudformation: Enable PostGIS Extension in RDS from Cloudformation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, postgis-installation

New to cloudformation. I am spawning PostgreSQL RDS instance using a aws cloudformation script. 
Is there a way to enable PostGIS (and other extensions) from aws cloudFormation script?

Answer (score 2):

> Working with PostGIS PostGIS is an extension to PostgreSQL for storing
>   and managing spatial information. If you are not familiar with
>   PostGIS, you can get a good general overview at PostGIS Introduction.
>
> You need to perform a bit of setup before you can use the PostGIS
>   extension. The following list shows what you need to do; each step is
>   described in greater detail later in this section.
>
> - Connect to the DB instance using the master user name used to create    the DB instance.
> - Load the PostGIS extensions.
> - Transfer ownership of the extensions to therds_superuser role.
> - Transfer ownership of the objects to the rds_superuser role.
> - Test the extensions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html

I'm not sure but maybe you can create a lambda function and RDS  with your cloudformation  and then you can invoke your lambda to do above steps. You need to try.

best,

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with `AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner`.

Basically we can run bash command with this (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to achieve it by using cloudformation. Cloudformation is a provisioning tool not a configuration management tool.